# Check for a Variable in Sass mixin & print it if it's defined

Tags: ruby, sass

I'm creating a Sass mixin with 3 arguments one of them is optional & I want to print it out if it's passed otherwise I don't want to print anything.

Here is how my mixin looks like:

```
@mixin name($arg1, $arg2, $arg3: false){
    @if $arg3 { #{$arg3} , }
    & {
        color: #{$arg1};
        > #{$arg2}{
            &:before{
                something...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but this doesn't work & it throws an error

> Warning: Syntax error: Invalid CSS after "...$arg3}": expected "{", was "}"

So how can I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be how you would write it:

```
@mixin name($arg1, $arg2, $arg3: false) {
    $sel: ();
    @if $arg3 {
        $sel: append($sel, unquote($arg3));
    }
    $sel: append($sel, unquote('&'), comma);
    #{$sel} {
        color: #{$arg1};
        > #{$arg2} {
            &:before{
                border: 1px solid;
            }
        }
    }
}

.foo {
    @include name(yellow, blue, '.bar');
}
```

Output:

```
.foo .bar, .foo {
  color: yellow;
}

.foo .bar > blue:before, .foo > blue:before {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

However, it might be better written like this:

```
@mixin name($arg1, $arg2) {
    color: #{$arg1};
    > #{$arg2} {
        &:before{
            border: 1px solid;
        }
    }
}

%foo, .foo {
    @include name(yellow, blue);
}

.foo .bar {
    @extend %foo;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But can you please explain your 1st solution, I want to understand exactly what's going on.

Comment: nevermind I got it, never knew that you can create an empty "list"? or the append() function in Sass.